# std::chrono::duration::max() doesn't work with thread support library

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, c++17, c++-chrono

I wish to create a wrapper around `std::timed_mutex` with the concept of INFINITY,NOTIMEOUT and valued timeout, instead of using different library calls (`lock`,`try_lock`,etc.).

I assumed that if I use the maximum resolution,`std::chrono::nanoseconds`, its `max()` duration will correspond to 292 years. Which is more than enough to represent the concept of INFINITY.

However I find out that doesn't work if I use STL `chrono` library helper types, i.e. `std::timed_mutex.try_lock_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds::max())` exits (`false`) immediately when the lock it's owned by other thread. Bellow a quick demo app.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

#define STR_ME(expr_)   #expr_

template <typename Duration>
void check_infinity(const char *name,const Duration &timeout)
{
    std::timed_mutex tmd_mx;

    tmd_mx.lock();  //mutex is locked by std::this_thread
    auto thread_f=[&](const char *name,Duration timeout)
                {   
                    if (!tmd_mx.try_lock_for(timeout))  
                        std::cout << name << " : TIMEOUT!!" << std::endl;
                    else
                        std::cout << "Green light..." << std::endl;
                };

    std::thread t{thread_f,name,timeout};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));   //Ensures thread "t" runs.    
    t.join();
    std::cout << "Houston??" << std::endl;  //Shouldn't reach this point ever.
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    check_infinity(STR_ME(std::chrono::nanoseconds::max()),std::chrono::nanoseconds::max());    //Fails
    //Every other STL chrono::durations fail.    

    using my_nanoseconds    = std::chrono::duration<unsigned int,std::nano>;   //STL uses long.
    using my_seconds        = std::chrono::duration<unsigned int>;  
    check_infinity(STR_ME(my_nanoseconds::max()),my_nanoseconds::max());  // Fails
    check_infinity(STR_ME(my_seconds::max()),my_seconds::max());  // Works !!

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

For this test I've used pthread library in ubuntu.

My questions are :

- Is this a "limitation" of pthread library? After all the `max()` duration corresponds to the `rep` maximum value.
- Are this max values defined somewhere?
- Are this max values related with CPU clock? And can vary depending on the architecture?
- Am I doing something foolish?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki "that doesn't work" means. `timed_mutex.try_lock_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds::max())` exits immediately with false if the lock it's owned by other thread, when it should wait `std::chrono::nanoseconds::mas()`

Answer (score 2):

[`std::timed_mutex::try_lock_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/timed_mutex/try_lock_for) computes a new `std::chrono::time_point`, at which the timeout should fire, based on the current point in time and adding the requested timeout duration.

For any non-zero point in time representing the current time (either time since epoch or time since last reboot), whose resolution is not less than nonoseconds (e.g., microseconds), such an operation overflows when adding `nanoseconds::max()` (adjusted to clock's resolution), i.e.:

```
steady_clock::now() + duration_cast<steady_clock::duration>(nanoseconds::max())
```

overflows just like:

```
int{1} + std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

overflows, because `std::chrono::nanoseconds::max()` returns [[time.traits.duration_values]/p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.traits.duration_values#6):

> ```
> static constexpr Rep max() noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Returns*: `numeric_­limits<Rep>::max()`.

Your clock's resolution is probably set to `nanoseconds`.

Comment: Good description as to what is happening.  As for where to go from here, I recommend creating a `years` duration and using `years{100}` for INF.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Then why did you invent the evil max and min function ??

Comment: So that if you feel the need, you can check if an expression is going to overflow prior to computing the expression.  E.g.  `if (x <= nanoseconds::max() - y) x += y;`.  It can be tricky to use correctly, and it is usually not needed.  But it is there if you need it, and doesn't cost you anything if you don't use it.  And the syntax without it is atrocious if you _do_ need it:  `if (x <= numeric_limits<nanoseconds::rep>::max() - y) x += y;`.